# How to release new Items in Scrapy in case item is not needed?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am running Scrapy 2.4 spiders in parallel that last for up to 24 hours per crawl. Especially at the end of the day the memory usage will accumulate constantly until the server runs out of RAM.

After looking into the memory leak topic I am wondering if this could cause the problem:

```
def parse(self, response):
     myItem = TestItem()
     # ... some code
     # return None in some cases due to error
     return None
```

During utilizing parse method I am creating a new Item and in some cases down the line I realize that this item is not good enough to be saved, so I exit the parse method by return None. Is this the appropriate way of doing it or could this be the problem regarding memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

You should debug memory leaks with trackref or muppy

> trackref is a module provided by Scrapy to debug the most common cases of memory leaks. It basically tracks the references to all live Request, Response, Item, Spider and Selector objects

More information is available in [scrapyDocs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html)